# Repeat input tag with new name using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm having a problem in jquery, I have a form with multiple div that have multiple inputs and repeats themself when i click on add button, the problem is the inputs that repeats have names in format `<input name="brand_meta[designer][1][name]" type="text" class="form-control" value="">`

when I press on add button I want them to repeat itself with new name `brand_meta[designer][2][name]`

my fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/prayaspanchuri/b2wskq1w/

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to name your fields that way? There is an easier way to name fields whose data you want to send in an array or serialize: `name="brand_meta[]"`. Otherwise, you will have to use REGEX to update the count yourself.

Comment: Why don't you use `band_meta[designer][]`? Most server languages will automatically convert these into an array.

Comment: Actully these are going to be added to wordpress post meta, and to fecht them in more descriptive way, I'm saving it this way, you can see the example here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/prayaspanchuri/b2wskq1w/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/b2wskq1w/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn.btn-default.btn-sm').bind('click',function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var n = +$('.'+id).length + 1;
        var html = $('.'+id).html()
        .replace(/\[\d+\]/g, '[' + n + ']');
        $( '.'+id+':last' ).after( $( '<div class="col-md-12"><hr style="border-top:1px #000 solid"></div><div class="'+id+'">'+html+'</div>' ) ).fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: Great! Glad this helped. Enjoy, and checkmark the answer when you get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $( '.'+id+':last' ).find('input').each(function(){
        var elemName = $(this).attr("name");
        var oldNameNum = parseInt(elemName.match(/\[(\d+)\]/)[1], 10);
        var newName = $(this).attr("name").replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, "["+(oldNameNum+1)+"]");
        $(this).attr("name", newName);
    });
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/b2wskq1w/2/

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want different names? You can use names arrray like city[] which will have all input data. But if you want different name you can use an hidden input to track the name of next fields like this

```
 <input type='hidden' name='counter' id='counter' value='1'>
```

and when duplicating inputs increase its value by 1 and assign its value to input name

like this

```
 $("#addbtn").click(function(e){
   var countertrack= $("#counter").val();
   var newname= parseInt(countertrack+1);
   /* then assign the name using this variable*/

 })
```